# How to get specific p-element inside div when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a several div elements like the one illustrated below:

```
<div class="div-bubble bubble">
    <p>This is the text I would like to get</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="action-link action" id="linkId">Yes</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="action-link action" id="linkId">No</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I click on either the yes or the no link in the li-element how can I then also get the above p-element? It must be in vanilla js.

Comment: what do you mean by get the p-element?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, its unclear what you are asking, to help you clarify, please review this documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet,

```js
function linkClick(e, id){  console.log(document.getElementById(id).closest('div').childNodes[1])
}
```

```html
<div class="div-bubble bubble">
    <p>This is the text I would like to get</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" onClick="linkClick(event, this.id)" class="action-link action" id="1">Yes</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="action-link action" id="2">No</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not working when clicking on the "no", as OP asked.

Comment: @TakitIsy it is an idea to solve the probleam, op only need to add onclick for get working

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do something like this:
(The only thing added is JavaScript, I didn't modify your HTML)

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('action-link');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.closest('div').getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="div-bubble bubble">
  <p>This is the text I would like to get</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="action-link action" id="1">Yes</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="action-link action" id="2">No</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It's better not to use inline javascript.

Hope it helps.